# Live reload of the Spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, maven

I work with Spring boot project and I would like to do live reload of the Java code while the app is running in the Apache Tomcat. I do little research and come up with information that with using the following dependency, it's possible to get the job done. The dependency is,

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
   <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

However, this is not working for me. Do I need to have something additional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo will need extension for Google Chrome:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei

Also configure your IDE to build project automatically

For Intelij Idea:

1. Settings -> Compiler -> "Build project automatically".
2. Press Ctrl + Alt +Shift + /, select "Registry" and enable compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running flag.